# XML schema - validate tag name by enumeration

Tags: xml, xsd

Guys.

I have a following XSD parts:

```
<!-- Enumeration of supported types -->
<xs:simpleType name="SupportedTypes">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="creditCard" />
        <xs:enumeration value="directDebit" />
        <xs:enumeration value="paypal" />
        <xs:enumeration value="webmoney" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

This works perfectly when I want to check the attributes values for instace (XSD below):

```
<!-- this is what I know how to make, not what I want to do :) -->
<xs:element name="PaymentType" type="SupportedTypes" />
```

But what if I have a list of payment types, e.g. (XML below):

```
<!-- existing XML that I need to validate (preferably by the same enum) -->
<paymentTypes>
    <creditCard price="123.50" />
    <webmoney price="100.00" />
    <directDebit never="true" />
</paymentTypes>
```

Is there a way to check the tag names agains an existing `SupportedTypes` type?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't use a declaration of a simple type to specify the names of child elements.

You could have a list of enumerations via `xs:list`, but you also want to associate price data with each entry, so a `xs:list` of `SupportedTypes` isn't really want you want.

You could have an attribute, `@type`, whose type could be `SupportedTypes`:

```
<paymentTypes>
    <paymentType type="creditCard" price="123.50" />
    <paymentType type="webmoney" price="100.00" />
    <paymentType type="directDebit" never="true" />
</paymentTypes>
```

Under XSD 1.1, you could even use *Conditional Type Assignment* to assign the type of the associated element based on the value of `@type`.

Or, you could keep your current XML and simply specify a normal content model for `paymentTypes` consisting of a sequence/all/choice of multiple, normally defined child elements, `creditCard`, `webmoney`, and `directDebit`.

---

**Update:** Or, as Michael Kay adds in the comments, you could use a ***[substitution group](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#key-equivalenceClass)***, as shown in [XSD element substitution group example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39868769/xsd-element-substitution-group-example).

Comment: Or use a substitution group, where paymentTypes has a content model as a repeating sequence of paymentType, and paymentType is an abstract element declaration with creditCard, webmoney, and directDebit in its substitution group.

Comment: @MichaelKay could you please make an example?

Comment: @MichaelKay: True, thanks.  t1gor: See [XSD element substitution group example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39868769/xsd-element-substitution-group-example).

Comment: @t1gor My general approach on this site is to point people in the right direction, not to give them a free ride to their destination. There are plenty of resources you can use once you know what construct you need to use.

Comment: Somehow I really missed the substritution groups. Thanks a lot!